# PHP Include database.php - error with fetching array options

Tags: php

new to PHP and wondering what what i might be doing wrong here, any ideas?

```
 public function connect() {    
    // Try and connect to the database
    if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
        self::$connection = new mysqli($options['db_host'],$options['db_user'],$options['db_pass'],$options['db_name']);
    }

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if(self::$connection === false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return false;
    }
```

I am including my database file in my functions.php

```
include('database.php');
```

which contains

```
$options = array(
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_user' => 'optimiser',
    'db_pass' => '4uju2yre8',
    'db_name' => 'zadmin_optimiser',
    'db_table' => 'files'
);
```

error:

> Undefined variable: options in
>   /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/optimise/functions.php on line
>   21

Anyone have any ideas on this? clearly im doing it wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to $options in the function. To do this, set it to global.

```
include('database.php');

public function connect() {    
    global $options;

    // Try and connect to the database
    if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
        self::$connection = new mysqli($options['db_host'],$options['db_user'],$options['db_pass'],$options['db_name']);
    }

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if(self::$connection === false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could include the database.php inside the function, or pass the $options as a parameter.

Comment: global is bad. Use function parameters like shown in the example below

Answer (score 1):

```
include('database.php');

public function connect($options) 
{
  // Try and connect to the database
  if(!isset(self::$connection))
    self::$connection = new mysqli($options['db_host'],$options['db_user'],$options['db_pass'],$options['db_name']);

  // If connection was not successful, handle the error
  if(self::$connection === false) 
    // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
    return false;
}
```

Because options is declared in the `database.php` you need to pass it in.